# Как добавить в яндекс map свои кнопки?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как свои кнопки отображать поверх яндекс карты как на этом примере? Если помещать в div, то они появляются отдельно от карты вверху, а мне надо именно чтоб они внутри карты находились.

Answer (score 0):

Оперируйте стандартными методами HTML и CSS, если собственные методы API Яндекс Карт вас не устраивают. Можно сделать примерно так:

```
<div id="map" >
    <div id="buttons" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; z-index: 1;">
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Кнопка 1"/>
        <input type="button" id="button2" value="Кнопка 2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```